# After Effects experience with virtual choir 3D environment

Tags: after-effects, 3d

Is there anyone in the forum with After Effects experience related to the production of a virtual choir, such as that of Eric Whitacre (e.g., see video below)?

I would like to get some advice on how to set up  the AE 3D environment for a similar production.

Comment: I think that setting up a 3D environment in AE which visually showcases video solids, as seen in your youtube link, is a fundamentally different question than coordinating/ arranging a virtual choir.  Which are you more interested in?

Comment: -1: Putting together a virtual choir video is a very large, involved process, one that is much too large and ambiguous for an SE site. Is there one particular step you want information on?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky video production technique. Anyway, try the following steps:

- First, create 4 black solid layers. Then, add a Lens Flare to them.

  - Place one flare in the bottom right corner.
  - On another solid, make the lens flare on the fare right middle.
  - For the third color solid's lens flare, make it on the top. With different color flares, it will look closer to what you are after.
  - Then, add a Ramp behavior to the last black solid and make sure it is on the bottom of the other layers.
- Also, make the top a light gray and the bottom a dark gray.
- Add an Adjustment layer above the black solids.

  - Add a Fast Blur to it and set it to around say 60, making the lens flares blurry.
- Select all of the layers and create a pre-comp.
- Meanwhile, try to add another color solid and make it white. Then, add a mask to it and make it an oval shape. Make the feather big like 250 or more. Move it so it is where the floor would be.

Comment: perhaps illustrations would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one place better than www.videocopilot.net for the solution to this problem.  Theres is Adobe AfterEffects for motion graphics and VC's plugin called Element, worth every expense for managing the scope of the video choir.  They have posted two very important tutorials with a particular toolset in AE called Sure Target and using 3D positioning mapped onto the globes in the video above, you should be able to achieve this result.
It is quite the project and they did a fantastic job producing the result in the virtual choir on TED Talks.  You can achieve similar results if you take a look at what I've posted.  Good luck…!

Comment: are you affiliated with this product in any way?  Your answer reads rather like a product placement.

Comment: And if you aren't affiliated, could you explain or summarize the answer rather than just saying that someone else has answered it? Clarity and completeness is a mark of a good Stack Exchange-style answer.